# How to get second Image from Mediafile in News Extension? [TYPO3]

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, tx-news

How can I get the second image in template for news extension of GeorgeRinger in TYPO3.

I extend the **showinpreview** field with "show in teaser" and I want to acces the second image, or better the image where "show in teaser" was set, in the templatefile for the teaser.

If I debug the newsItem.mediaPreviews, there ist only one image, but I set two in the backend… so how can I get the other image.

Thanks

TYPO3: 9.5.14
news: 7.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check out the model `News` you will see this:

```
public function getMediaPreviews()
{
    $configuration = [FileReference::VIEW_LIST_AND_DETAIL, FileReference::VIEW_LIST_ONLY];
    return $this->getMediaItemsByConfiguration($configuration);
}
```

This means that you only get those with the allowed types.

---

As a solution there are 2 options:

- use `{newsItem.getMedia}` and check in the `<f:for>` for the value
- extend the model with a custom getter method which returns the ones you need

Comment: The first solution seems to work, but it's {news.media} in fluid ;) Thanks - Now I'll try the second solution, i think it's better to have an own field with the teaser-images, preventing too mutch conditions in fluid. ;)